# What is red Chinese BBQ sauce called?

Tags: chinese-cuisine, restaurant-mimicry

Does anybody know what the bright red bbq sauce served in Chinese restaurants is called? I'm trying to find a recipe for it but don't know what to look for.

It's usually served with ribs or pork, it's not the dipping sauce served on the tables, def taste of star anise in it and I think it's made from scratch as I've asked in many Chinese supermarkets if it comes in jars or powder form to be told no. The colouring is added to make it red.

Comment: 35karen35, welcome! Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] - one of the things we *don't* do here is recipe requests. To get started, use your favourite search engine: [this is the first hit](http://www.food.com/recipe/chinese-barbecue-sauce-128611) I got when searching for "chinese bbq sauce". If you need help *improving* or *changing* a recipe, we'll be glad to add our two cents. That said, I'm looking forward to more contributions as your question is well-thought through, especially pointing out the research you already did and the flavour components you identified.

Comment: I would guess the name of the sauce you are after is Char Siu sauce. The anise taste you mentioned would be from the Chinese five spice used in it.

Comment: @StephenAsherson that is an answer [to the SE appropriate question "What is the name of that Chinese red bbq sauce ...?" as oppose to the recipe request], could you add it as an answer.

Comment: I think you might be aiming for Xá Xíu. I have a recipe for the sauce for Xá Xíu that I designed in my teens, but I can't swear that it is exactly authentic; it was based on the sauce used at a local Chinese restaurant at the time. It's good enough that it's still being used now that I'm in my 50s, and several Chinese friends have requested it. If you are interested, please leave a comment. I can post it here, e-mail it, or e-mail the .pdf version. I'm not certain of the rules for posting recipes, so I leave it to my SE elders to shut me down or redirect me to the proper way to go about this.

Comment: @Shalryn, [we don't to recipe requests](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but there's always [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan)...  OP needs 20 rep, but that's only two votes on an answer, for example.

Comment: @Stephie Voting to leave open. I think a small edit would move it from the recipe request category into restaurant mimicry.

Answer (score 2):

Char Siu sauce ( char siu = fork roasted )